# Create array of objects using distinct values from two arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested-loops

My question is a little more involved. I have two arrays of data:

```
var arr = [
  {title: "foo", namesIndices: [0,1]},
  {title: "bar", namesIndices: [2]},
  {title: "baz", namesIndices: [3,4]}
];

var names = [
  {name: "John", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Mike", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Jane", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Ali", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Robert", website: "someUrl"}
];
```

Where namesIndices will reference an index in the names array that will correspond with that person with their title. In order to match the person's name and website with the correct title to make this array:

```
var person = [
  {name: "John", title: "foo", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Mike", title: "foo", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Jane", title: "bar", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Ali", title: "baz", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Robert", title: "baz", website: "someUrl"}
];
```

I have had to loop through the first array, then loop through arr.namesIndices:

```
var person = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].namesIndices.length; j++) {
        var personObj = {};
        personObj.title= arr[i].title;
        personObj.name = names[arr[i].namesIndices[j]].name;
        personObj.website= names[arr[i].namesIndices[j]].website;
        person.push(personObj);
     }
 }
```

Is there a way to do this without nested loops?

Comment: You can unnest the loops sure, but you're still going to need those for loops somewhere since you're going to have to loop through both arrays at some point. Why do you want to remove the nesting?

Comment: The data that comes through could get pretty large. Not enough to have nested loops really be a concern, but as a general rule I try to stay away from it.

Comment: Why is `namesIndices` an object instead of an array like `[0, 1]`?

Comment: Your inner `for` loop treats `namesIndices` as if it were an array, not an object.

Comment: If you make it an array, you could then use `indexOf()` to search for the value.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I am making the correction now. I had misread the data from the server.

Comment: With indexOf(), you are looping again, so from a Big-O standpoint, I don't gain much that way.

Comment: How big is your data set? I think you may be over optimizing here looking at Big-O for a single nested loop. If the data is really that massive, you might want to use a different language where you can break apart the data and run it on multiple threads. I see no way to loop through these arrays, without looping through the arrays.

Comment: You're right @James Hay. I am over optimizing. Thanks for the input!

Comment: If the arrays are large, you can convert the array you're searching into an object, so you can O(1) lookups. But for small data, `indexOf` should be fine. Yes, it's a loop under the covers, but you don't have to write it out in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `map()` to avoid explicit loops altogether if you wish.

```
var arr = [
  {title: "foo", namesIndices: [0,1]},
  {title: "bar", namesIndices: [2]},
  {title: "baz", namesIndices: [3,4]}
];

var names = [
  {name: "John", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Mike", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Jane", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Ali", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Robert", website: "someUrl"}
];

var person = arr.reduce(function (accumulator, titleAndIndices, arrIndex) {
    var newEntries = titleAndIndices.namesIndices.map(function (index) {
        var rv = names[index];
        rv.title = arr[arrIndex].title;
        return rv;
    });
    return accumulator.concat(newEntries);
}, []);

 console.log(person);
```

Comment: Are implicit loops better than explicit ones?

Comment: Functional reactive JS types seem to think so. But if you were to say that the code I wrote above is not an improvement over the original code, I would not argue.

Comment: +1 You're answer also has the advantage on modern browsers of having those looping functions (`map`,`reduce`) implemented natively, which will likely be faster than interpreting a JavaScript `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Still requires two loops, but they're not nested now:

```
var arr = [
  {title: "foo", namesIndices: [0, 1]},
  {title: "bar", namesIndices: [2]},
  {title: "baz", namesIndices: [3, 4, 5]}
];

var names = [
  {name: "John", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Mike", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Jane", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Ali", website: "someUrl"},
  {name: "Robert", website: "someUrl"}
];

var people = [];

var makePeople = function(title, indices){
    for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){
        people.push({
            name: names[indices[i]].name,
            title: title,
            website: names[indices[i]].website
        });
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    makePeople(arr[i].title, arr[i].nameIndices);
}
```

It's not exactly shorter though, and it does basically the same thing.

Comment: Yeah. As I said, it shouldn't be a big deal to have the two loops. I was hoping someone knew of a method that could do this better. I was looking into .map(), but couldn't work it out that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without nested loops?

No. And there is **nothing wrong** with it. Your data comes in a nested format, so it is totally natural to consume it with nested control structures. That still has `O(n)` complexity, where `n` is the amount of data (and `n = al * ni` with the `arr` length and the average number of `namesIndices` per item)

Comment: Thank you. I understand this, and I know that there won't be an issue it this instance. I am a student, and it has been pretty engrained in us so far that we should avoid nesting loops wherever possible. This is a personal project that I am working on and I am just looking to see if there is a different way to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to destroy your `arr` array and repurpose your `names` array (as the accepted answer does), you can reach your goal via a simple recursive function. I'm considering this to be loopless since it doesn't use loop syntax. I think that's about as close as you can get to looplessness, short of hardcoding a separate process for every array index.

**Recursive function**

```
var person = (function func(obj) {
  names[obj.namesIndices.pop()].title = obj.title;
  return obj.namesIndices.length ? func(obj) : arr.length ? func(arr.pop()) : names;
})(arr.pop());
```

You could preserve the original arrays if you made the function keep track of the array indexes instead of using pop(), but I didn't have the patience to do it that way :).

If you can tolerate a single loop, then you can replace the nested one with conditional statements that determine which counter to increment. Unlike the previous example, this one doesn't alter the original arrays.

**Single loop**

```
var person = [];

for(var a = arr.length - 1, n = arr[a].namesIndices.length - 1, obj, i;;) {
  i = arr[a].namesIndices[n];
  obj = names[i];
  person[i] = {name: obj.name, website: obj.website, title: arr[a].title};
  if(n) n--;
  else if(a) n = arr[--a].namesIndices.length - 1;
  else break;
}
```

I haven't properly tested the performance of these two techniques, but I believe it will be at least comparable to that of the nested loop, and better than any solution that involves Array iteration methods like `reduce`, `map`, `forEach`, etc.